# How can I use .net(not core) on my Macbook?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I do not wanna set up virtual machine on my macbook. I downloaded Rider on my laptop. However, I cannot see templates like(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLXbP.png). May you help me about it?

Thanks from now.

Comment: You can't run .NET Framework code on a Mac - or at least, you could try using Mono, but I suspect you'll find it awkward. If you want to develop for a Windows-only framework, you should use Windows. Note that just ".NET" now refers to the portable .NET 5, .NET 6 etc - and that *does* work on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .NET 5 or higher on a Mac, it's cross-platform. .NET Framework, on the other hand, is not cross-platform unless you use something like [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/), which I wouldn't recommend doing unless there's a very specific reason to do so.   If you need to develop a Windows app, you're better off using a Windows device.

I'd suggest looking into the differences between .NET, .NET Framework, and .NET Core, if you're not already aware of them, because the naming does not make it particularly clear.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible without any other software like a VM to emulate the windows environment.

"Yes, compiled applications that target the .NET framework will absolutely not run on MacOS, or Linux, or Solaris or..... anything not Windows. .NET core is now portable to MacOS though."

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/444456/net-framework-45-and-visual-studio-for-mac-8102.html